# POST request done successfully but data not saved in database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to save form data in database by POST request, request successfully done but data not saved in database.

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='images')
   tagName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   instance = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**forms.py**

```
class BuildImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    fields = ('user', 'tagName', 'instance')
    model = Image
```

**views.py**

```
class BuildImage(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
   form_class = BuildImageForm
   model = Image
   template_name = 'images/buildImage.html'
   success_url = 'user/gui'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    objectlist = request.user.instances.all()
    return render(request, 'images/buildImage.html', {'form': forms.BuildImageForm,
                                                      'objectlist': objectlist})

def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save()
    instance.user = self.request.user
    instance.tagName = self.request.tagName
    instance.instance = str(self.request.instance_name)
    instance.save()
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

**Update - Edited**
I have update my view as:

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BuildImageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
            form.instance.tagName = data['tagName']
            form.instance.instance = data['instance']
            form.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Now it prints that error in console:

> `<ul class="errorlist"><li>instance<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
>   [23/Jul/2017 04:36:56] "POST /user/images/buildImage/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your view method like this,

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = self.request.user
    instance.save()
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly assign the data other than user from cleaned_data to the instance. Model forms are there for that. You only need to assign user to the instance. The rest are already assigned when you submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

you are actually saving the file before adding data

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = self.request.user
    instance.tagName = self.request.tagName
    instance.instance = str(self.request.instance_name)
    instance.save()
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: Hi @Exprator ! take a look on question's update, please!

Answer (score 0):

try to set try and cache for database operation 
may be there is some error cached in cache section

**Update**

```
try:
 "save to database code here" 
except Exception as e: 
  print "error here" print e
```

Comment: try:
   "save to database code here"
    
except Exception as e:
    print "error here"
    print e

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been solved just by providing a title attribute in my template for instance input field.

Updated code as:

**buildImage.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="dockerForm">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset>
                        {% if not objectlist %}
                            <h3><strong>Sorry!</strong> You couldn't have created any Instance yet! <strong>Let's <a href="{% url 'users:create' %}">Create One </a></strong></h3>
                        {% else %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><label for="package">Select Your Instance:</label></span>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <select class="form-control" name="instance" id="instance_id" title="Select your Instance">
                                    {% for element in objectlist %}
                                        <option value={{ element.name }}> {{ element.name }} </option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

**forms.py**

```
class BuildImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    fields = ('tagName', 'instance')
    model = Image
```

**views.py**

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BuildImageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
            form.instance.tagName = data['tagName']
            form.instance.instance = data['instance']
            form.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:gui'))
```